# Is there a problem with inheriting from threading.Thread without actually starting the thread?

Tags: python

I've created a Python class which inherits from `threading.Thread`, instances of which may not actually be run as a new thread (because the `start()` method is never invoked). The code has been written such that it works whether start() has been invoked or not (just in a slightly different way). This is entirely intentional.

Is there a problem or overhead with not ever invoking the start() method on an instance of the class? Is there a better way to write a class that is sometimes run in a new thread and sometimes not?

Inheriting from Thread insists on appending a Thread-n to the repr() string on the class instance, even if it isn't running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view a slightly cleaner design would be to *not* inherit your class from `threading.Thread`, but keep its `run` method as-is.

Now:

- if you don't need threading, you can continue to use your class as you do currently;
- if you do need threading, create a new `Thread` object, setting the `target=` constructor argument to your object's `run` method.

Comment: So, to clarify, in order to keep the same interface, I don't inherit from `threading.Thread` and just write my own `start()` method that creates a new Thread using the `target=` constructor arg.

Comment: @Henry Gomersall: Yes, something along these lines. Without seeing the code it's hard to give precise recommendations for what exactly needs changing.